# A better Angular way to build multi-field model/value?

Tags: angularjs

My model, which I'm about to send to the api, wants a DoB of the form dd-mm-yyyy.

i.e.

```
    vm.Manifest = {
        Driver: {
            dateOfBirth: "17-11-1969"
        },
    };
```

My view has three separate fields.

I thought what I might do is have a hidden field that concatenates the three fields on-the-fly:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label text-right">Date of Birth:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <select ng-model="adminManifestVm.Manifest.Driver.Day"
                ng-options="day.val as day.name for day in adminManifestVm.controls.days"
                name="Day"
                class="form-control input-inline input-small"
                required>
            <option value="">Day</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="adminManifestVm.Manifest.Driver.Month"
                ng-options="month.val as month.name for month in adminManifestVm.controls.months"
                name="Month"
                class="form-control input-inline input-small"
                required>
            <option value="">Month</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="adminManifestVm.Manifest.Driver.Year"
                ng-options="year for year in adminManifestVm.controls.yearsAge"
                name="Year"
                class="form-control input-inline input-small"
                required>
            <option value="">Year</option>
        </select>


<!-- this field is hidden but contains the formatted date -->

        <input type="text" name="dateOfBirth" 
           ng-value="adminManifestVm.Manifest.Driver.Day +
                     '-' +
                     adminManifestVm.Manifest.Driver.Month +
                     '-' +
                     adminManifestVm.Manifest.Driver.Year">

        <div class="error-message" ng-show="manifestForm.$invalid && (manifestForm.Day.$touched &&  manifestForm.Month.$touched &&  manifestForm.Year.$touched) || adminManifestVm.submitted">
            <span ng-show="manifestForm.$error.required">Your full birth date is required.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works, but is there a more Angular way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a angular version that supports `ng-model-options` then you can bind to a getterSetter. You can read up more on the `ng-model-options` directive [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#binding-to-a-getter-setter)

> Sometimes it's helpful to bind ngModel to a getter/setter function. A
>   getter/setter is a function that returns a representation of the model
>   when called with zero arguments, and sets the internal state of a
>   model when called with an argument. It's sometimes useful to use this
>   for models that have an internal representation that's different from
>   what the model exposes to the view.

This solution requires you to change your model structure a bit.

Please see working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/1yud38g2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" data-ng-controller="TestController as vm">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>DOB</label>
          <label>{{driver.dateOfBirth.date()}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <select class="form-control" style="width:120px" ng-options="day for day in days" ng-model="driver.dateOfBirth.day" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"></select>
          -
          <select class="form-control" style="width:120px" ng-options="month for month in months" ng-model="driver.dateOfBirth.month" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"></select>
          -
          <select class="form-control" style="width:120px" ng-options="year for year in years" ng-model="driver.dateOfBirth.year" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"></select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.days = [];
  $scope.months = [];
  $scope.years = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
    $scope.days.push(i);
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    $scope.months.push(i);
  }

  for (var i = 1990; i <= 2016; i++) {
    $scope.years.push(i);
  }

  $scope.driver = {
    dateOfBirth: {
      day: function(day) {
        return arguments.length ? (this.day = day) : this.day;
      },
      month: function(month) {
        return arguments.length ? (this.month = month) : this.month;
      },
      year: function(year) {
        return arguments.length ? (this.year = year) : this.year;
      },
      date: function() {
        if (!isFunction(this.day) && !isFunction(this.month) && !isFunction(this.year)) {
          return this.day + '-' + this.month + '-' + this.year;
        } else {
          return '';
        }
      }
    }
  };

  function isFunction(obj) {
    return typeof obj === "function"
  }
}]);
```

You can then just send the `$scope.driver.dateOfBirth.date()` to the API

Comment: Thanks. A couple of questions about that. 1] The object I'm going to pass to the API is specified in the opening post (vm.Manifest). This driver method is its *own* method, right? Would it make sense to label it vm.DriverDoBSetter or something? 2] I can't point the function *directly* to the API - it is nested within vm.Manifest. So I guess I need to do some sort of vm.Manifest.driver.dateOfBirth=vm.DriverDBSetter.dateOfBirth()

Comment: You can do as you mentioned `vm.Manifest.driver.dateOfBirth=vm.DriverDBSetter.dateOfBirth‌​()` when posting to the API. So your UI will bind to a different object than what you send to the API.

Comment: Ah. Got it working. Thank you! And now I know how to use gettersetters.

Comment: Shoot. It only works on one set of fields. I've got two. I guess making it reusable will have to wait for another time.